# How do i see which softwares are installed in ubuntu?

Tags: software-sources

How can i get a list of my installed applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open Ubuntu software center and click at Installed applications.

[image]

Comment: No you can not see it from desktop but you can see it from unity DASH.

Comment: No you can see all installed applications.

Comment: ok ya i got that.thnx